# R: Cut equivalent for strings

Tags: r, stringr

I have a list of different types of masks and I would like to categorise them into those that are N95, surgical, cloth or other.

```
     df<-data.frame(mask_type=
c("Surgical Mask (3M 1800)",                                                                      
     "N95 FFR (Wilson 1105N) (2x 3mm leaks)",                                                        
     "N95 FFR (San Huei United Company 1895N) (2x 3mm leaks)",                                       
     "Surgical Mask (Primed  PG4-1073) (2x 3mm leaks)",                                              
     "Surgical Mask (3M 1800) (2x 3mm leaks)",                                                       
     "N95 FFR (Wilson 1105N) (4x 3mm leaks)",                                                        
     "Cloth FFR (San Huei United Company 1895N) (4x 3mm leaks)",                                       
     "Cloth Mask (Primed  PG4-1073) (4x 3mm leaks)")
```

This works that filters the masks but doesn't create an "other" column. Am I far away do you think?

require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

```
df %>%
  mutate(TYPE=stringr::str_detect(mask_type,"N95 | surgical | cloth")) %>%
  filter(TYPE=TRUE) %>%
  select(mask_type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_extract` to extract if any of the pattern `'Surgical|N95|Cloth'` is present in the string. If none of it is present it will return `NA` which can be replaced with `'Other'`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(TYPE= str_extract(mask_type, regex('Surgical|N95|Cloth', ignore_case = TRUE)), 
         TYPE = replace(TYPE, is.na(TYPE), 'Other'))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I'm finding it's complaining about "could not find function regex". Is theat from a different package? I looked at stringr's page and it seems like it's inbuilt so I'm a bit confused. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is weird. Yes it is from `stringr` so if you have loaded that package it should work without any error. I used it to make the regex case-insensitive. You can check the answer without it `TYPE= str_extract(mask_type,'Surgical|N95|Cloth')`

Comment: Thank you again for your help. If I use require(stringr) instead of stringr::str_extract it works fine. Odd, no?

Comment: Should also work fine if you do `library(stringr)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
lst1 <- with(df, regmatches(mask_type, gregexpr('Surgical|N95|Cloth', mask_type)))
df$TYPE <- sapply(lst1, function(x) if(length(x) == 0) 'Other' else x)
```